# Google maps no funciona en mi web pero si en fiddle

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

Tengo un [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/yorch/7hrxrL6f/7/) que funciona perfectamente, ahora quiero subirlo a mi servidor, para ello lo he separado en 2 archivos, `map.html` y `map.js`.

**map.html** *pongo una key provisional que he creado (no se si es ese el problema) también he probado estáticamente con `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">` pero sin éxito.*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CERVEZAS ARTESANAS DE BARCELONA</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="map.js" ></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDrwvmO8LJ_mYkFsdIkZ6EFXi-dWwfH05M">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map-canvas" style="width:1100;height:600px" >
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**map.js**

```
var map;
var nombres = [
    "CERVE", 
  "DOSS", 
  "TRRES", 
  "QUATTRO", 
  "QUATRE PEDRES"];
var direcciones = [
    "D__UNNO", 
  "D__DOSS", 
  "D__TRRES", 
  "direccion", 
  "cosas y cosas<br>Badalona"];
var marker;
var markers = [];
var coordenadas = [
  "41.3985452,2.1988172",
  "41.4016108,2.1611477",
  "41.3810539,2.1503189",
  "41.3921943,2.1166733",
  "41.4381275,2.232936"
];
var x;
var y;
var contadorMarcas = 0;
var cliente;
var icon = {
    path: "M-10,0a10,10 0 1,0 20,0a10,10 0 1,0 -20,0",
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: .6,
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    strokeWeight: 0,
    scale: 1
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.38, 2.18);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);

  // añadimos cada punto
  coordenadas.forEach(function(entry) {

    var data = entry.split(",");
    setMarker(data[0], data[1], nombres[contadorMarcas], direcciones[contadorMarcas]);

    contadorMarcas ++;
  });
}

function setMarker(x, y, nombreCliente, tooltipInfo) {
  // cogemos el color que corresponde al cliente
  var pinColor = "AFAFAF";
  var pinImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter_withshadow&chld=%E2%80%A2|" + pinColor,
    new google.maps.Size(34, 34),
    new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    new google.maps.Point(10, 34));

  // toltip para cada
  var tooltipHTML =
    '<div id="content" ' +
    //'style="width:400px;">' +
    '   <div id="infoWindow' + nombreCliente + '">' +
    '   </div>' +
    '   <h2 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">' + nombreCliente + '</h2>' +
    '   <div id="bodyContent">' +
    '       <p><b>' + tooltipInfo + '</b></p>' +
    '   </div>' +
    '</div>';

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});
  var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(x, y);

  // ponemos el marker en el mapa
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: pos,
    map: map,
    icon: pinImage,
    title: nombreCliente,
    icon: icon
  });

  // le incrustamos el tooltip
  bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, tooltipHTML);

  // y lo ponemos en el array general
  markers.push(marker);

}

// permite que cada marcador muestre su propio tooltip 
function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, strDescription) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(strDescription);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
    infowindow.close();
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function() {
    $(".gm-style-iw").next("div").hide();
  });
}
```

Pero cuando lo ejecuto [**en mi web**](http://greenardo.cat/new/map/map.html) y local tengo el siguiente error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined

En la primera linea que se utiliza la libreria de maps:

```
anchor: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mira, lo que veo es que te falta cerrar la etiqueta script de la url, en el archivo de map.html. Ya lo probé y me funciona correctamente.

Ademas debes cambiar el orden de ejecución de los scripts.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDrwvmO8LJ_mYkFsdIkZ6EFXi-dWwfH05M"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="map.js" ></script>
```

Comment: he arreglado eso, pero me sigue dando el mismo error, puedes postear el codigo corregido? soy un parras con el html.... `XD` gracias!

Comment: Lo había olvidado, tambien tienes que color primero el script de la url y después el de map.js.

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDrwvmO8LJ_mYkFsdIkZ6EFXi-dWwfH05M"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="map.js" ></script>

Comment: corrige la respuesta para completarla :)

Comment: Listo ;), me había olvidado.

Answer (score 2):

Cambia el orden de los scripts (cargar primero google maps) y cierra su etiqueta script:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDrwvmO8LJ_mYkFsdIkZ6EFXi-dWwfH05M"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="map.js" ></script>
```

Comment: parece que funciona, porque importa el orden de los scripts?

Comment: Porque estás llamando elementos a partir de map.js que no existen aún en el DOM, de ahí la importancia del orden, digamos que es una especie de dependencia.

Comment: ostia claro!!! que bueno.... cosa más aprendida... en java no tenemos estos problemas :D

Comment: tienes mi +1 pero voy a aceptar la respuesta de gibrán que ha sido el primero y tiene mucha menos rep... espero no te importe :)